# How to prove that Fractional Knapsack exhibits Greedy Strategy.?

Tags: algorithm, knapsack-problem

How can i prove that Fractional Knapsack exhibits Greedy Strategy,

I can do it practically but i am not able to find a method to prove it theoretically.?

Please help
Thanks in Advance

Comment: What kind of answer do You expect?

Comment: theoretrical answer which i can write to prove this question

Comment: The question is interesting but looks like a homework assignment! No effort were shown into solving it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to show that this problem has the greedy choice property. To do this, we need to show that any solution `X` which does not include the greedy choice `a` does not have get a worse solution after swapping some choice with `a`.

For fractional knapsack, this is very easy to show: we take any element of `X`, say `b`. If w<sub>a</sub> >= w'<sub>b</sub> (where w<sub>a</sub> is the weight of `a`, and w'<sub>b</sub> is the weight `b` has in the solution `X`), we can replace `b` with as large a fraction of `a` as possible. Because `a` is the item with the largest value-density (this is our greedy choice), this will not make the solution worse. If w<sub>a</sub> < w'<sub>b</sub> we can take all of `a`, and make w'<sub>b</sub> = w'<sub>b</sub> - w<sub>a</sub>. Again, because `a` has the largest value-density, this does not make the solution worse.

That's it! We technically also need to show optimal substructure, but that should be fairly straightforward for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The (primal) fractional knapsack LP is

```
maximize sum_{i=1}^n v_i x_i
subject to
y: sum_{i=1}^n w_i x_i <= W
z_i: x_i <= 1  (for i=1 to n)
x_i >= 0  (for i=1 to n),
```

where `v_i` is the value of item `i`, and `w_i` is the weight. The dual LP is

```
minimize W y + sum_{i=1}^n z_i
subject to
x_i: w_i y + z_i >= v_i
y >= 0
z_i >= 0  (for i=1 to n).
```

By (weak) LP duality, if the greedy solution to the primal has the same objective as a solution to the dual, then both are optimal. Assume that all weights are positive, that their sum is greater than `W`, and that the item are ordered so that `v_1/w_1 >= v_2/w_2 >= ... >= v_n/w_n`. Let `j` be the pivot item, so that the greedy primal solution is

```
x_1, x_2, ..., x_{j-1} = 1
x_j = (W - sum_{i=1}^{j-1} w_i) / w_j
x_{j+1}, x_{j+2}, ..., x_n = 0.
```

By complementary slackness, we can guess that, in the dual, we should have

```
z_j, z_{j+1}, ..., z_n = 0.
```

The `x_i` constraint in the dual is equivalent to

```
y + z_i/w_i >= v_i/w_i,
```

so we need to set

```
y >= v_j/w_j >= v_{j+1}/w_{j+1} >= ... >= v_n/w_n
```

in order to satisfy the constraints where we have zeroed `z_i`. On a hunch, we set

```
y = v_j/w_j,
```

which intuitively forces the assignments

```
z_i = (v_i/w_i - v_j/w_j) w_i  (for i=1 to j-1).
```

Now comes the only part of this argument that needs to be rigorous: verifying that this is a feasible solution to the dual (tedious and thus left as an exercise) and that the objective matches the greedy primal solution. The objective is

```
W y + sum_{i=1}^{j-1} z_i =
W (v_j/w_j) + sum_{i=1}^{j-1} (v_i/w_i - v_j/w_j) w_i =
sum_{i=1}^{j-1} (v_i/w_i) w_i + (v_j/w_j) (W - sum_{i=1}^{j-1} w_i) =
sum_{i=1}^{j-1} v_i + ((W - sum_{i=1}^{j-1} w_i) / w_j) v_j,
```

which is indeed the primal objective.